# Java Virtual Machine Emulator

Tags: jvm, emulation, bytecode

I want to execute java bytecode (JVM Instructions) line by line and also want to see the stack value, registers etc. like wise we can do with emulators available for 8086 microprocessors.

So is it possible to do with JAVA bytecode? Is there any emulator available?

Comment: A software being able to execute java bytecode isn’t an emulator—it’s a JVM, by definition. And yes, such software exists, e.g. [Oracle has such a JVM](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html) which has a debug mode which allows executing the code step by step and inspecting the values, see http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/platform/jvmti/jvmti.html#whatIs

Comment: I think using `JVM TI`, I can watch the sate of JVM, but I need to code. Can I have any ready made tool?

Comment: Every Java debugger will do. Check out the well-known IDEs, Eclipse and Netbeans. Both are open source, hence, you can expand their capabilities if they don’t meet all of your needs.

Comment: As per my knowledge java debugger can not do that. If it does than how to  do it. Please share it with me.

Comment: this should be on [softwarerecs.se]